# Objective-c Changing the font of a given text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string

I'm working on a little iphone app. I'm trying to change the Font and Color of the text inputed by the user. They type something and then click a button and the font or color is changed and displayed. I can't seem to find any example code of this online. Could anyone should me how this might be done? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can be more specific if you elaborate on where you are storing the text and displaying it from, but here's a basic example of applying a font change to a label.

```
[myLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"someFontName" size:19]];
```

EDIT:

```
- (IBAction)changeFont:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [myLabel setText:myTextField.text];
    [myLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"someFontName" size:19]];
}
```

Comment: Sorry i'm still very new to this forume, and coding. I have a UITextField that the user inserts any text, then i have 3 buttons which change the font or color. once a button is clicked the changed font is redirect to the UILabel. Did that make sense? Also if anyone knows of any tutorials that do this that would be awesome if you could share it with me.

Comment: @JamesHall I don't know of any, but you should be able to Google for each of the basic operations you would have to perform to make this happen. I've edited my post to include and IBAction that would set the text of a label to what ever text was contained by a text field.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what sort of interface you want to use for displaying the text with the changed font/color. A [`UITextField`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) has a `font` property and a `textColor` property so you could just change them. Similarly for other places where you might display text.